# Event in color picker HTML5

Tags: html, knockout.js, color-picker

I am working with HTML5 color picker and knockout js. I am trying to capture and update the color. Which is the event that gets fired up when i select a color from color picker.

Answer (score 5):

The color picker fires the `changed` event so you can just use the `value` binding to get the currently selected color:

```
<input type="color" data-bind="value: color" />
Selected: <span data-bind="text: color"></span>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MCSB4/).